# What's the wrong on my for statement; getting undefined offset?

Tags: php

I keep getting undefined offset.. what would be the problem with this?

```
for($m=0; $m<=count($data); $m++){ // (this is where it points)
  if(date("m-Y",strtotime($data['data'][$i]['date_d'])) == $curdate)
    $sum.$cmonth +=1;
  else
    $sum.$cmonth = 0;
}
```

Comment: You should remove the `count()` from the loop as you are running the function every time needlessly

Comment: What is `$i` doing in your code shouldn't it be `$m` ?

Answer (score 2):

That is because , adding a `<=` will make your loop iterate till the non-existent index of the array. ,  Rewrite like this.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){ // (this is where it points)
  if(date("m-Y",strtotime($data['data'][$i]['date_d'])) == $curdate)
    $sum.$cmonth +=1;
  else
    $sum.$cmonth = 0;
}
```

I recommend a `foreach` instead.

```
foreach($data as $k=>$v)
{

}
```

Comment: Really he should take the `count` out of the loop!

Comment: @shankar: removed the = but still getting undefined offset

Comment: @user3404341, First of all you had a problem with the variable name.. Secondly the `<=` issue. You need to change both of em for your code to run correct or you can copy paste the code I had put up on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see your array to be multidimensional and you are running the loop on second index so do like

```
for($m=0; $m<count($data['data']); $m++){
```

This will consider the length of the array(if there is any) named `data` inside the `$data` variable.

**And change your $i to $m**(if you are trying to traverse that array usinf the loop) like

```
if(date("m-Y",strtotime($data['data'][$m]['date_d'])) == $curdate)
```